# Csv file uploader on APEX which previews the data on an interactive grid for editing?

Tags: oracle-apex

Any resources on how I can create a csv file uploader on APEX which previews the data on an interactive grid for editing and changing data before uploading to a table?

Answer (score 0):

Loading the csv:

1. Create a data load definition in shared components for your file, target type table. Create a table for this in which you'll temporarily store your data.
2. On the page, create a file upload item
3. In page processes, create a process of type Data Loading, use Data Load definition from step above.

Previewing the csv

1. Create an IG region on the table you use in Data Loading config.
2. When preview is complete, copy the data in to the actual table.

That is the raw outline of what you need to do, I left out the details. But there are plenty of resources on how to do each step avaiable on the web.